# angluarjs ng-option with template inside

Tags: angularjs, ng-options, angularjs-ng-options

I want to create a dropdown select with text and an icon.
My start point is this:

```
<select ng-change="actions.change()"
        ng-model="variant_id"
        ng-options='variant.id as variant.name for variant in variants'>
</select>
```

but in the instead of showing name, i want to put something like this:

```
<div>{{variant.name}} <span ng-show="variant.show">show!</span></div>
```

how can i do it in ng-options?

Comment: An `<option>` can [only contain character data](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/option.html). So what you're trying to do is not possible. You'll have to create your own directive (probably using `ngRepeat`).

Comment: Thanks! do you mean using ngRepeat with `<ul><li>`?

Comment: Basically yes, though have a look at the link sylwester posted. Why *reinvent the wheel* ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't put html inside option tag.

But you can use it https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select or other simmilar 'plugins'